# Panel gridline disappear after setting panel background color in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a plot with ggplot2. After I modify the panel background color to white (or other color, or even transparent), the gridline disappears. How can I get the panel gridline back? Thank you.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=hp))+
    geom_point()+
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white')) # or other color, or 'transparent'
```

Comment: You can try `theme_bw()` or `theme_classic()` as well

Answer (score 2):

By default the gridlines are also white, so of course you won't be able to see them if the panel background is white.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=hp))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = 'black'),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = 'grey'))
```

[image]